# How to create a WSDL for my JSP Page

Tags: web-services, jsp, wsdl

I have a working JSP page (with one parameter). Now somebody wants to use my JSP as a webservice.

How can I create a WSDL for my JSP, and how do I passthrough parameters

I'm able to to create a WSDL and test it, but I'm unable to read my parameter `request.getParameter` in the JSP.

Comment: This makes honestly said no sense. JSP is a web view technology, not a web service technology.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into some existing framework, like [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) or [jax-ws](http://jax-ws.java.net/), for creating web services. Doing SOAP manually tend to get...messy.

Comment: Found the parameters in the body :-) request.getInputStream()

Comment: Again, I would suggest using technologies and frameworks developed for this purpose, rather than inventing the wheel all over again. It's your funeral though.